# Using the same shortcode to show any table from the database

Tags: php, shortcode, mysql, wpdb

I have a little question for you.

I want to create a shortcode that makes a table with data that I have stored in a database. But i want to send the shortcode an attribute, to specify which table (database) I'd like to show.

```
add_shortcode("list", "list");

function list($tbl) {
    extract(shortcode_atts(array('item' => '')), $tbl);
    if($item!="") {
        $mydb= new wpdb('root','root','mydb','localhost');
        $rows = $mydb->get_results("select * from ".$item);
        echo "<table>";
        foreach ($rows as $obj) {
            echo "<tr>";
            //Here I want to put the content of the row
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";
    } else {
        echo "<h2>Table does not exist</h2>";
    }
}
```

The shortcode would be something like this:

```
[list item="table1"]
```

How can I use the same shortcode to show any table of a database? How can I manage each row to show all the fields it has got? Because i have different tables with different number of columns and different column names, and i want to display each cell in a in the table.

Thanks!

Comment: The basic idea you have is correct. That is the WordPress part. The fine details are really just pure PHP.

Comment: Just solved it.. Can't add an answer here because ofmy reputation (i'm new). here is the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21912972/using-the-same-shortcode-to-show-any-table-from-the-database/21914019#21914019